# XML Getting attibute value of a Node

Tags: c++, xml, xmldom

I am using XML DOM API in C++ to parse an XML file. I can't find any method to get the attribute value in a node element.

For example, in the following xml

```
<test>
<fruit count="10">
...
...
</fruit>
<test>
```

I need to get the count string("10") using XML APIs. Can anybody help me with some code snippets.

Comment: Which XML DOM API?  There are quite a few.

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM Parser API to get attribute value count.

Refer below sample code:

```
//code to perform some process for parsing the input file and get rootElement

DOMNodeList* fruitNodes= rootElement->getElementsByTagName(XMLString::transcode("fruit"));

DOMNode* node = fruitNodes->item(0);

DOMElement* fruitElement = dynamic_cast <xercesc::DOMElement*>(node);

const XMLCh* attrValue = fruitElement->getAttribute(XMLString::transcode("count"));
```

you can get value 10 from attrValue using: `string(XMLString::transcode(attrValue))`

Comment: Nice solution! Remember to use the built-in editor to format your code. This makes it easier for other users to find an read your code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx

Try something like:

```
pXMLDomNodeList = pXMLDocElement->selectNodes("/test/fruit/@count");
```